# Using MATLAB's chi2gof with non-standard user-specified PDFs

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability-density, cdf, goodness-of-fit

I would like to use MATLAB's `chi2gof` to perform a chi-square goodness-of-fit test. My problem is that my assumed (i.e., theoretical) distribution is not one of the standard built-in probability distributions in MATLAB. The specific form of my desired distribution is:

```
p = x^a*exp(-b*x^2)
```

where `a` and `b` are constants. There must be a way to use `chi2gof` for arbitrary PDFs? I have done an exhaustive Google search, but have come up empty-handed.

Comment: You can use [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to generate numbers from arbitrary distributions.

Comment: Is the actual issue that you don't know how to find the CDF for your distribution (`chi2gof` has an option to the CDF of an arbitrary hypothesized distribution)? What is the name of your distribution, by the way? @jadhachem: I don't understand your comment. I don't think that the issue is with generating random numbers from the distribution, but rather how to check the fit of existing data with the particular distribution.

Comment: @horchler My bad, I guess I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @horchler: I have an "analytical" expression for the CDF involving the incomplete gamma function. My issue is how to code the problem. Suppose, for instance, my CDF was given by F(x)=a*exp(-bx-cx^2) [b,c,>0]. (Assume a,b,c are known constants.) What would the call to chi2gof look like? I know it would involve using a function handle, but I am not sure how to code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a [handle to a function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) that takes a single argument to [`chi2gof`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html) this way:

```
a = ...
b = ...
c = ...
F = @(x)a*exp(-b*x-c*x.^2); % Technically this is an anonymous function
[H,P,STATS] = chi2gof(data,'cdf',F)
```

Or in special cases:

```
a = ...
b = ...
c = ...
F = @(x,a,b,c)a*exp(-b*x-c*x.^2);
[H,P,STATS] = chi2gof(data,'cdf',{F,a,b,c})
```

the last line of which is equivalent to

```
[H,P,STATS] = chi2gof(data,'cdf',@(x)F(x,a,b,c))
```

If the parameters `a`, `b`, and `c` are estimated (e.g., using some fitting process), then you should specify the number of estimated parameters to `chi2gof`. In this case:

```
[H,P, STATS] = chi2gof(data,'cdf',F,'nparams',3)
```

Please read the documentation to learn about the other options.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will emulate your code with my real F(x). As a sidebar, I was also confused about the difference between a function handle and an anonymous function, but your comment resolves that query.